# How to solve List is not callable in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have encounter this `List is not callable` error.
What should I do to prevent this from happening? Thanks!

```
def PrintTxt(src, beg, end):
    with open(src, 'r') as f1:
        srctxt = f1.readlines()
        for line in srctxt(beg, end):
            print(line)

Filepath = 'C:\test.txt'

PrintTxt(Filepath,1,5)
```

Comment: If you're trying to slice the list, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: You will need to escape the backslash: `Filepath = 'C:\test.txt'` -> `Filepath = 'C:\\test.txt'` or pass a raw string: `Filepath = r'C:\test.txt'`

Comment: You could also use `islice(f1, beg, end)` from itertools.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be unaware of the correct [Python slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html). After:

```
srctxt = f1.readlines()  # now srctxt is a list
```

you can slice the resulting `list` like:

```
for line in srctxt[beg:end]:
    # ....
```